# How to vertically align CSS columns content?

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm trying to build a simple layout with an unordered list, using CSS columns so I can organize its content in two columns if there are too many items in the list, so far I'm able to get this to work like this:

```css
.slide {
  width: 874pt;
  height: 492pt;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

ul.product-list {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 10%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  columns: 200px auto;
}

ul.product-list li.product-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

ul.product-list li.product-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul.product-list li.product-item img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
}
```

```html
<section class="slide">
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="product-list">
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

However, I'm trying to make it so that the list is vertically aligned at the center of the container when there are just a few items, so it looks like this:

```css
.slide {
  width: 874pt;
  height: 492pt;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

ul.product-list {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.product-list li.product-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

ul.product-list li.product-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul.product-list li.product-item img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
}
```

```html
<section class="slide">
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="product-list">
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Since the contents of the list will fill up dynamically,I want them to stay aligned at the center of the container, is this possible to achieve with this markup and css columns? If not, what would be a good way to get this layout to work?

Comment: I think you have to use tables element for the vertical alignment to work

Comment: use fixed heights on each element. eg: height: 5vh; width: 5vh;

Comment: @Stanley I'm not following, you mean adding that to each `.product-item`?

Comment: why are you using absolute position?

Comment: @ZiadDarwich because in the actual document I have another element in the `.slide` container, is the absolute position an issue in this situation?

Comment: @IvanS95 never mind, misunderstood the question, is this what you want? https://i.gyazo.com/979e635e59d52bba65553e6084766375.png

Comment: @Stanley that's what I want, but to keep the list aligned like that and also be able to split it into 2 columns if it runs out of vertical space

Comment: no, but it will cause different problems especially in different screen sizes, if you can get rid of it it would be better

Comment: @ZiadDarwich it won't cause issues, the container has a relative position so the list inside will be positioned only within the boundaries of the container, which itself has a fixed width and height, so it won't behave differently regardless of screen size.

Comment: @IvanS95 I posted an answer, does that seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**change flex direction and add flex to blue container**

[image]

```css
.slide {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgb(163, 163, 163);
  }
  
  
    
    ul.product-list li.product-item {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        break-inside: avoid;
    }
    
    ul.product-list li.product-item:not(:last-child) {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    ul.product-list li.product-item img {
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: 74px;
        height: 74px;
    }

ul.product-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 80vw;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    margin: 0 auto;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 90vw;
    border: 3px solid red;

    margin: 0 auto;
}

.product-item {

    border: 3px solid lime;
    padding: 1vh 1vw;
}
```

```html
<section class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <ul class="product-list">
        <li class="product-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
          <span>Item</span>
        </li>
        <li class="product-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
          <span>Item</span>
        </li>
        <li class="product-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
          <span>Item</span>
        </li>
        <li class="product-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
          <span>Item</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <ul class="product-list">
        <li class="product-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
          <span>Item</span>
        </li>
        <li class="product-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
          <span>Item</span>
        </li>
        <li class="product-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
          <span>Item</span>
        </li>
        <li class="product-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
          <span>Item</span>
        </li>
        <li class="product-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
          <span>Item</span>
        </li>
        <li class="product-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
          <span>Item</span>
        </li>
        <li class="product-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
          <span>Item</span>
        </li>
        <li class="product-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
          <span>Item</span>
        </li>
```

Comment: This does work fine, was trying to see if it was possible to do it with CSS Columns though, it solved my issue, so I'll check this as correct and add my own answer as well since I managed to do it with CSS Columns and no Flexbox for people that might want to take the same approach :)

Comment: @IvanS95 that is great! One problem, multiple approaches, even more answers!

Answer (score 1):

The following css should do what you asked for:

```
    .slide {
      width: 874pt;
      height: 492pt;
      margin: auto;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      background-color: #FFF;
    }

    ul.product-list {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: center;
      height: 500px;
    }

    ul.product-list li.product-item {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    ul.product-list li.product-item img {
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin-right: 10px;
      width: 74px;
      height: 74px;
    }
```

Make sure to apply the *content* class to the *ul* element. Here is a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-drxsme?file=style.css)

Comment: I need the wrapping div, I'll add more details to the question, the thing is I have this `.slide` which has a title and then the list to the right of the title, so I'm already using flexbox to align those two things vertically

Comment: You can nest flexboxes. The other problem is the position absolute. I managed to get it working check the updated answer and stackblitz example

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate solution using only **CSS Columns** in the unordered list element, in this case the items in the columns align at the top, but the list itself stays vertically centered while more items are added.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide {
  width: 874pt;
  height: 492pt;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

ul.product-list {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: fit-content;
  max-height: 100%;
  left: 10%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 35px 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  columns: 200px auto;
}

ul.product-list li.product-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

ul.product-list li.product-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul.product-list li.product-item img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
}
```

```html
<section class="slide">
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="product-list">
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="slide">
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="product-list">
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="product-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="">
        <span>Item</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```